# Nested UIAlertView logic

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview, nested

in my app I have button, that allows user to buy current item.

I want user to confirm, that he accepts selling agreement, and then he selects his preffered payment method.

My logic behind this is following.

After user click buy button, following UIAlertView pops up:

```
NSMutableString *msg = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"By recognizing this agreement you agree, that in following 15 minutes you will pay for %@ which has price of %@, if you won't make the payment, your account may be blocked for this item.",mainTitle.text,buyoutPrice.text];
    UIAlertView *buyoutAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buyout" message:msg
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"I don't agree" otherButtonTitles:@"I agree",nil];
    buyoutAlert.tag = 1;
    [buyoutAlert show];
```

In my - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
I'm checking whether he accepts...

```
        - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(alertView.tag == 1)
        {
            if(buttonIndex == 1)
            {
                UIAlertView *typeBuyout = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Anonymous payment", nil)
                                                       message:NSLocalizedString(@"Do you wish to make payment as anon?", nil)
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"Anon buyout",@"Regular buyout",nil];
                typeBuyout.tag = 2;

                [typeBuyout show];

            }
        }


if(alertView.tag == 2)
{

        if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            //anon
            NSLog(@"anon");
        }else if(buttonIndex == 2)
        {
            //normal 
            NSLog(@"Normal");
        }
    }
```

My problem is, that after presenting user second Alert (typeBuyout) and after user makes his choice clickedButtonAtIndex doesnt fire.

I've tried to define my typeBuyout alert in viewDidLoad and in clickedButtonAtIndex just [typebuyout show]; but with same results.

Comment: IN TH SECOND ALERT U ARE  NOT GIVING DELGETE  SELF U ARE GIVING NIL CHECK IT OUT

Comment: (I probably need more time to look at this) but is the delegate:nil intentional?

Comment: 08442, thx!!! you are right, please write it as an answer so I can accept :)

Comment: NaN, no, he was right, I just copy-pasted previous alert because I'm lazy idiot (one which didn't have to use delegate method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second alert you are not giving delegate self, you are making it nil. Check it out

Comment: Why are you using Only Capital letters ?

Answer (score 2):

Set delegate for second alertview to call `clickedButtonAtIndex` method

```
if(buttonIndex == 1)
 {
            UIAlertView *typeBuyout = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Anonymous payment", nil)
                                                   message:NSLocalizedString(@"Do you wish to make payment as anon?", nil)
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Anon buyout",@"Regular buyout",nil];
            typeBuyout.tag = 2;

            [typeBuyout show];

        }
```

Comment: Thank you Nazik, I'll upvote but accept 08442's answer because he was first to point out my lazy-noob mistake.. But thx alot for taking time!